# ActionBarSherlock AND GoogleLicenseCheck

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock, extend

I want to give my app a facelift to use the Holo-Theme, even for old devices (SDK 8 and up).
So I tried to add the libraries "ActionBarSherlock" and "HoloEverywhere" to my app.

My Problem now is that I have to extend my class to the "SherlockActivity" instead of the "Activity".
But I am using the Google Licensing also. So I have already extended my class to the "LicenseCheckActivity".
I can not extend twice.

So what should I do to use both (GoogleLicensing AND the SherlockActivity)?

Answer (score 1):

There's really no LicenseCheckActivity class on th SDK, so my assumption is that you (or someone on your team) are using that LicenseCheckActivity to wrap all the license checking code according to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html).

If that's the case, all you need to do is open your LicenseCheckActivity and make that activity extend from `SherlockActivity` instead of just `Activity` and then you'll be able to take advantage of ActionBarSherlock while still keeping you license checking code.

Comment: Thats right. It is implemeted as documented. I am not sure in which activity I have to extend, cause the licensing stuff is a library. I just call (checkLicese();) in my Main activity. It seems that it is in the "LicenseChecker.java" in the licensing lib.

Comment: Wich library are you using? Is it an in-house project or something like http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/

Comment: It is the LVL from AndroidPit which checks the AndroidPit and the Google LVL: http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/developer-licensing-howto

Comment: As far as I can see there's no requirement on AndroidPit or Google LVL to extend from a LicenseCheckActivity. Where are you getting that class from? Which package?